# how can I save my python output from XML file to txt

Tags: python, xml, csv, pycharm, txt

I have selected a few specific fields from my xml file. How can I sav my python OUTPUT in a txt or csv file?

so when I print the following name fields from my xml file

```
        # print(name1, name2, name3)
```

**example OUTPUT:**

```
Em, Dee, G
Joe, Lia, Sia
Bigs, Sia, Chi

        # import csv
        # with open("file.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        #     fieldnames =["name1", "name2", "name3"]
        #     thewriter =csv.dictwriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        #     thewriter.writeheader()
```

I have tried the following however, my txt file looks really messed up

Comment: with open('file.txt', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerows(zip(name1, name2, name3)    # I also tried this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save in CSV file:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    fieldnames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
    writer.writerows([fieldnames])
```

To save in a text file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    fieldnames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
    text_file.writelines(", ".join(name for name in fieldnames))
```

Hope this willl help you.